# Numpy multiply 3d matrix by 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I got matrix A of shape (3,2,2), e.g.

```
[
[[1,1],[1,1]], 
[[2,2],[2,2]], 
[[3,3],[3,3]]
]
```

and matrix B of shape (2,2), e.g.

```
[[1, 1], [0,1]]
```

I would like to achieve c of shape (3,2,2) like:

```
c = np.zeros((3,2,2))
for i in range(len(A)):
    c[i] = np.dot(B, A[i,:,:])
```

which gives

```
[[[2. 2.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[4. 4.]
 [2. 2.]]

 [[6. 6.]
 [3. 3.]]]
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((2),(1))) gives [[[2 1] [2 1]]  [[4 2], [4 2]] [[6 3] [6 3]]], which is different from what's expected. What should be the correct way in my case, please?

Comment: What would be typical shapes of A and B? The performance of various methods would depend on them.

Comment: A is of shape (n, 2, 2), where n can be rather large. B is always of shape (2, 2). Which method would be preferred please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and then swap axes. So, use one of these -

```
np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((1),(1))).swapaxes(0,1)
np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((1),(1))).swapaxes(1,2)
```

We can reshape `A` to 2D after swapping axes, use 2D matrix multiplication with `np.dot` and reshape and swap axes to maybe gain marginal performance boost.

Timings -

```
# Original approach
def orgapp(A,B):
    m = A.shape[0]
    n = B.shape[0]
    r = A.shape[2]
    c = np.zeros((m,n,r))
    for i in range(len(A)):
        c[i] = np.dot(B, A[i,:,:])
    return c  

In [91]: n = 10000
    ...: A = np.random.rand(n,2,2)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(2,2)

In [92]: %timeit orgapp(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

In [93]: %timeit np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((1),(1))).swapaxes(0,1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((1),(1))).swapaxes(1,2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 208 µs per loop

# @Bitwise's solution
In [95]: %timeit np.flip(np.dot(A,B).transpose((0,2,1)),1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 697 µs per loop
```

Comment: @dxli Did this post solve your question? If so, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
np.flip(np.dot(A,B).transpose((0,2,1)),1)
```