# Numpy: multiply 3D array with 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays, one of shape `(4, 2, 2)`, another of shape `(4, 2).`

```
A = np.random.rand(4, 2, 2)
B = np.random.rand(4, 2)
```

So, for every `0<= i <= 3`, I want to have `np.dot(A[i, :, :], B[i, :])`.

How to do it without using a for-loop?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796440/numpy-multiply-3d-matrix-by-2d-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(A @ B[...,np.newaxis])[...,0]` should work (synactic sugar for `np.matmul(A, B[...,np.newaxis])[...,0]`).

Per [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) for `matmul`:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes.

You can also use Einstein summation `np.einsum("ijk,ik->ij", A, B)`, although on my machine this is apparently slower than broadcasting matmul:

```
import timeit

import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(4, 2, 2)
B = np.random.rand(4, 2)


def broadcast_matmul():
    return (A @ B[..., np.newaxis])[..., 0]


def list_map():
    return np.array(list(map(np.dot, A, B)))


def einsum():
    return np.einsum("ijk,ik->ij", A, B)


print(timeit.timeit(broadcast_matmul))
print(timeit.timeit(list_map))
print(timeit.timeit(einsum))

# Results on my machine:
# 1.870921753
# 6.705698656999999
# 2.765732645
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how this could be done using `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', A, B)

array([[0.39437083, 0.45360039],
       [0.75211742, 0.40669922],
       [0.18131254, 0.19473085],
       [0.2919673 , 0.10398859]])
```

---

Quick check using the first elements that are multiplied:

```
np.dot(A[0], B[0])
# array([0.39437083, 0.45360039])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
`list(map(np.dot, A, B))`